# Rename default button in the Date Picker(android)

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

How i can rename default button("SET") in the  DatePicker dialog?

My dialog:

```
case IDD_SET_NAME:
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
myYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
myMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
myDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
DatePickerDialog DatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
return DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `DatePickerDialog` Set button text as:

```
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, myCallBack, myYear, myMonth, myDay);
datePicker.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Enter text here", datePicker);
```